# Android - Cannot use "import com.google.gdata.data.youtube" in my project

Tags: java, android, android-youtube-api

I think i have downloaded the correct .jar files but i cant seem to access com.google.gdata.data.youtube to get VideoEntry. Can someone please direct me to where this .jar file is.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
        compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.1'
        compile files('libs/gdata-client-1.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.21.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.21.0.jar')
    }
```

Ive been searching the web for this .jar file and cant find it.

Comment: Can you try using this dependency as well? `'com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1'` (don't know if it's the latest release)

Comment: pamobo0609: your a legend thanks mate

Comment: No problem at all dude, glad to help :)